# What is the largest amount of messages that can be stored in an AWS SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am creating an AWS SQS standard queue to store some data temporarily and then retrieve it later. I plan to enqueue about 10^5 to 10^6 messages. I was wondering what is the maximum number of messages the queue can store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From AWS Docs:**

> Q: How large can Amazon SQS message queues be?
> A single Amazon SQS message queue can contain an unlimited number of messages. However, there is a 120,000 quota for the number of inflight messages for a standard queue and 20,000 for a FIFO queue. Messages are inflight after they have been received from the queue by a consuming component, but have not yet been deleted from the queue.

https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/